# Should an Account Suspension Incur a Reputation Penalty?

Tags: discussion

My understanding is that, after an account suspension (during which time their reputation is 'locked' at `1`) has been served, the user's reputation is "recalculated" - meaning, I take it, that they will have their reputation restored to its full value, according to the usual calculation algorithm. (This could actually end up being *higher* than before the suspension if, say, folks had upvoted their posts during the aforementioned hiatus!)

But it is also my understanding that, if a particular user incurs a certain number of "bad" [comment] flags (rude/abusive flags, for sure, maybe others), they can have (up to) 100 points deducted from their rep.

These two rules seem to me to be mutually incongruous!

Would it, perhaps, be appropriate for a suspension to incur a reputation penalty of some sort? For example, assuming the length of the suspension reflects the severity of the misconduct, one could reduce the user's rep by a given percentage, calculated from the number of days of suspension, possibly up to a maximum value; say, 1% of reputation (or 100, whichever is the greater) loss for each day.

After all, reputation is how the Community 'judges' a user's overall (positive) contribution to Stack Overflow! Bad behaviour should surely be considered when assessing this.

Comment: Comment flags don't give any rep penalty. Rude/abusive or spam flags only give a rep penalty on sites with reputation (as in not meta) provided it's on a question or answer.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl OK, maybe I misread the rule about rude/abusive flags. But still, if they incur a rep penalty, then why not suspension?

Comment: If you served your suspension, your plate is clean. We don't keep reminding users that they are bad people. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions

Comment: I think there should be *less* gamifying, not more. Or if more gamifying aspects are to be added, then make them *positive* for some aspect that actually deserves attention. For example, reward people for finding duplicates or something else that helps the *content*. We've always been for content over users. Reputation is just to motivate people to curate and contribute to the content.

Comment: @rene A very good point! I don't know how frequent suspensions are (hopefully rare) and, also, I would imagine that "repeat suspensions" would generally move towards an outright ban - so maybe reputation loss is an unnecessary 'deterrent'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your title first:

> Should an Account Suspension Incur a Reputation Penalty?

No, it should not.

From Jeff Atwoods' blog [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

> We don't hold grudges.

And Jon Ericson added to that in his [Why we don't keep public records of suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions)

> The immediate effect of a suspension is removal. If a user has been rude or destructive, the community needs that behavior to stop and removing the instigator suffices. However, the long term goal is rehabilitation.

Reputation is the sum of all valued contributions a user made to the community and that value doesn't change. If the user exhibits behavior that is troublesome in some way, a suspension can help to put a stop to the behavior. It always requires a moderator to make that call. A suspension is not handed out at a whim. Once the suspension is served we should be done with it. There is no need to know or remember (for us mortals)  that a user was once suspended.

The -100 penalty a user receives when one of their posts receives 6 red flags (spam / rude) is of a different order and with a different goal. Posting spam or offensive stuff is relatively easy. The -100 reputation is there as an immediate stop gap measure. If they gained some rep, the -100 probably puts them back in a territory where they can do less damage. It might even trip all the quality ban algorithms if not an IP ban. That puts a stop to the ability to post content.

**tl;dr** Behavior and reputation based trust are different things and need different handling. Mixing or combining the two is not needed as it might interfere with rehabilitation within the community. Everyone is allowed a second (or third, or fourth) chance.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the 'different circumstance' for the -100 penalty on spam/rude flags.

Answer (score 10):

I just recently came back from a year long suspension, and seems I got about ~2000 points during that time. It wouldn't make a difference (to me) whether I got 2000 points, got zero points or lost 2000 points.

Of course I've got a buttload of points, but I can't see it having much of an effect on low-point (nothing to lose) or middle-point (practically nothing to lose) users either. It would be more of a lesser additional penalty tacked on, because banning is a stronger tool than decreasing points would be. Like getting jail time and having to pay a fine, except you pay the fine in imaginary money.

So not only would it be quite irrelevant / ineffective (would someone think "well, I wouldn't have done this if I had lost points...being banned is nothing"?), but as rene pointed out, it's also not the policy.

VLAZ's comment about gamification is relevant though. It can be a good tool to get people involved, but it can become increasingly complex if you notice that you've created a platform with virtual money, and try to keep it "fair" to everyone. As an example, there are a lot of "virtual poor" users who simply can't rack up points because they have a hard time answering, and to get question points you generally need a very good question. So they can't get even enough points to write comments, which I can imagine feels quite non-inclusive.